# joomla 1.5 community builder and

Tags: joomla1.5

joomla 1.5
Here is the site that I'm getting a lot of spam at. I'm getting Spam from registration & the guestbook components.These can be found under components section of the Joomla backend. For the registration I'm using 'Community Builder'. For the guest book I'm using 'Phoca Guestbook'. 
please help....

Comment: Means All the mails are sent to spam folder.. Right? Need clarification form your side...?

Comment: for the registration i am using community bulider when i register at that time confirmation  mail has been come to spam not inbox.

Comment: This issue was not in that component. Contact your hosting team , they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try installing a third party CAPTCHA extension such as the non-commercial EasyCalcCheck Plus. The Joomla 1.5 version isn't supported any more but can still be downloaded from:

http://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/downloads/ecc-easycalccheck-plus/joomla-15

The latest version (for Joomla 2.5) supports Community Builder and Phoca Guestbook and the Joomla 1.5 version probably does too.